# Insert date in filename while knitting document using RStudio Knit button

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I would like to include the current date in the output filename when knitting a document using RStudio's knit button. I can somehow change the options of the markdown rendering, but I don't know how. Could anyone point me into the right direction?

Comment: As a workaround, you could use `render` and its argument `output_file`.

Comment: could you please elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is almost the same as dd3 suggested.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do this in the console:

```
library(knitr)  
knit("test.Rmd")
knit2html("test.md", output=paste0("test",Sys.Date(),".html")) # Sys.Date() is a string with the current date
```

Alternate, better version:

```
rmarkdown::render("test.Rmd",output_file=paste0('test',Sys.Date(),'.html'))
```

You can directly change the behavior of the RStudio knit button with some code in your document, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28500096/r-markdown-variable-output-name).

To the header, before the output section add this code:

```
knit: (function(inputFile, encoding) { rmarkdown::render(inputFile, encoding = encoding, output_file = paste0(substr(inputFile,1,nchar(inputFile)-4),Sys.Date(),'.html')) })
```

The `substr(inputFile,1, nchar(inputFile)-4)` strips the ".Rmd" from your Rmd filename.

Comment: thanks a lot, but i would prefer to get this automatically done when i press the knit button.

Comment: @user3908149 if you click the little gear next to the knit button, you can see the options available to you using the GUI.

Comment: @user3908149 scratch that - you can insert some code into your markdown document to dynamically name the output file, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28500096/r-markdown-variable-output-name

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing with parameters but it doesn't work - the `knit_to_parameters:` part of the YAML header is ignored and the output html file still has the same name as the .Rmd