# Set output_file in YAML

Tags: r-markdown

When I run `render("test.Rmd")` with these YAML parameters, the output is still `test.docx` and not `teeeeeeeest.docx`:

```
---
title: "mytitle"
author: "Me, myself and I"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
output: word_document
output_file: "teeeeeeeest.docx"
---
```

However, if I set the argument inside the render function (`rmarkdown::render("test.Rmd", output_file = "teeeeeeeest.docx")`), it works fine.

Is it possible to set the `output_file` argument inside the YAML header? Else, my purpose is to include the current date in the output file name when knitting with RStudio, how could I do that?

Comment: perhaps this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28500096/r-markdown-variable-output-name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/rmarkdown-html-url-name-different-from-rscript-name/1578), it is possible to set the output file name inside the YAML by customizing the knit function within the YAML header. For this, you just need to add a 'knit:' hook in the header, such as in this example:

```
knit: (function(inputFile, encoding) { 
      rmarkdown::render(inputFile,
                    encoding=encoding, 
                    output_file='new_file_name.html')) })
```